# Mozilla Thunderbird HTTP Authentication

Tags: firefox, thunderbird, php, http, authentication

I set up Mozilla Thunderbird on Windows 7 Enterprise, and I set my main page to my own site. (Which requires HTTP/1.1 authentication).

Before I even have an HTTP authentication window (displayed for HTTP authentication in most browsers), it displays my custom 401 message set on the webserver.

Is there any Thunderbird plugin to fix this? or do I have to make do, or do I have to code an extra login form in PHP?

If I have to set up a PHP login form, how do I setup an HTTP Authentication form as a webpage?

Answer (score 0):

see if password manager has a blank or incorrect password stored, if so delete the entry.

Options --> Security --> Passwords --> Saved Passwords

Comment: I never had the chance to get the HTTP request window where I can input my password. Still, thanks for your help attempting to help me.

Comment: you might check anyway, I've found problem entries before.

Comment: Yeah I did... and I never realize that I can check my passwords this way. Although it didn't actually "help" me by directly answering the question.